# About the ending of The Fundamentals of Caring (Spoiler)

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, fundamentals-of-caring

In [The Fundamentals of Caring](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2452386/) (2016)

Ben is writing a novel about Trevor at the end and writes

> On his 21st birthday, I found him lying on the floor of his bedroom, finally at peace.

After a thoughtful pause, he writes again:

> He was faking of course. Anna quit the next day.

Was Trevor really faking it, or was he dead? The pause makes me think that Ben made up that ending in his head just then, as a way to sort of keep Trevor alive.

Comment: Either you believe him, or you don't. It is left open deliberately.